# How to convert list of strings to list of float or integers for mean conversion?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split, average

please help, i'm using python 3.4 and i'm trying to figure out how to convert a list of string numbers into a list of string int or float so i can get mean of x and y cordinates.
mycode.

```
filH = open('regres.dat', r')
fileL = filH.readlines()
for line in fileL:
i = line.split(",")
tl_list = (I[0],'\t',x[1])
xx_list = (tl_list[0])
yy_list = (tl_list[2])

S = (sum(xx_list)/float(len(y_list))
print(s)
```

I keep getting the error str to int.
I tried .lstrip but is not working, as well as running it through a loop for n.
could there be a faster way to strip my list of end ccommas.

Comment: you forgot a ' in open('regres.dat', r'): it should be : `open('regres.dat', 'r')`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to do mathematical operations on strings.

```
S = sum(map(float,xx_list))/len(y_list)
```